# How to reshape a 2-D linearized Array in Scala without loops

Tags: arrays, scala, matrix, functional-programming

I would like to know how to reshape a 2-D linearized Array in Scala without loops, i.e. by using functional programming.

Assume a 2-D Array of 6x12 = 72 elements. What I need is to resize this Array so that it has 8x16 = 128 elements, assuming that the new elements are initialized to zero.

This is how I do it with loops:

```
val a = (1 to 72).toArray
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72)

scala> val h = 6
h: Int = 6

scala> val w = 12
w: Int = 12

scala> val H = 8
H: Int = 8

scala> val W = 16
W: Int = 16

scala> val b = Array.ofDim[Int](H * W)
b: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

for (i <- 0 until h)
  for (j <- 0 until w)
    b(i * W + j) = a(i * w + j)

b: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

The question is: **how to do this by using functional programming?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.grouped(w).map(_.padTo(W, 0)).padTo(H, Array.fill(W)(0)).flatten.toArray
```

Result (and string copied from your code, for comparison):

```
result        : Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
b: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```